# How to click a button that appears as a label?

Tags: python, selenium

[Image of the code and what the button looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQPxt.png)

Im trying to click that add button but I cant find anything that says button when i inspect element

Here is my python code im trying to get work but not sure how to do it

```
buttonclick = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('add-vehicle-container')
buttonclick.click()
time.sleep(1)
```

Errors im getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ttttt/iCloudDrive/Documents/GitHub/SeniorProject2019TBA/Selenium/AboutYouTesting.py", line 50, in <module>
    buttonclick.click()
  File "C:\Users\ttttt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\ttttt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\ttttt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ttttt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <div class="add-vehicle-container"> could not be scrolled into view
```

Comment: What did this code do? I suspect it gave an error. If I am correct, please post the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run one of these commands in the developer console.

```
getEventListeners($("#SomeElement")[0]); //Javascript
$._data($("#SomeElement")[0], "events"); //JQuery
```

These will tell you if the events attached are indeed "click" events, or some other type of event.

If it is indeed a click event, you can try this:

```
driver.execute_script("$('.add-vehicle-container').click()");
```

If that does not work, or the events are not click events, then you can run this:

```
driver.execute_script("$('.add-vehicle-container').trigger('ATTACHED_EVENT_NAME_HERE')");
```

You can play around with these to see if they work by simply running them in the browser developer console before trying them in your python script.

Comment: How would run those last two in the browser arnt those Selenium commands